# How to define an array that must contain all values of a specific const enum?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have

```
const enum MyEnum {
    A = 'a', 
    B = 'b', 
    C = 'c'
}
```

I need a type of array with the required all elements ['a','b','c'] (the order of elements doesn't matter)

Comment: Short of using a dependently-typed language like Agda, I don't think this is going to happen at the type-level. You could use a class (or newtype) whose constructor checks the constraint at runtime, but that's of course relying on runtime assertions.

Comment: For example:   type Array2 = ['a', 'b']; const v: Array2 = ['a', 'b'] – and it will check correctly. Why is it not possible to define such array type from <keyof typeof MyEnum> ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to lose the `const` part, you can do it easily:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 'a', 
    B = 'b', 
    C = 'c'
}

console.log(Object.values(MyEnum));
//  ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use `UnionToTuple` type

```
const enum MyEnum {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b',
    C = 'c'
}

type MyList = UnionToTuple<MyEnum>
//   ^?
// type MyList = [MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C]

// magic
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
    U extends never ? never : (arg: U) => never
) extends (arg: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type UnionToTuple<T> = UnionToIntersection<
    T extends never ? never : (t: T) => T
> extends (_: never) => infer W
    ? [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, W>>, W]
    : [];
```

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298

Comment: Uh that issue is declined because this is not supported.  Right now this is like saying “all you need to do is stick a fork into an electrical outlet” without any caveats.